# org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity. Hibernate Mapping Exception

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, hibernate-mapping

I have 2 tables: Accounts and AccountDetailsData. I mapped there are to 2 classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Accounts", schema = "dbo", catalog = "core")
public class AccountsEntity {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
@Basic
@Column(name = "status")
private String status;
@Basic
@Column(name = "enabled")
private Boolean enabled;
@Basic
@Column(name = "timestamp")
private Timestamp timestamp;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="accountsEntityObject")
private List<AccountsDetailDataEntity> detailDataEntity;
public AccountsEntity() {
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public Boolean getEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}

public void setEnabled(Boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}

public Timestamp getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public void setTimestamp(Timestamp timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    AccountsEntity that = (AccountsEntity) o;

    if (enabled != null ? !enabled.equals(that.enabled) : that.enabled != null) return false;
    if (id != null ? !id.equals(that.id) : that.id != null) return false;
    if (status != null ? !status.equals(that.status) : that.status != null) return false;
    if (timestamp != null ? !timestamp.equals(that.timestamp) : that.timestamp != null) return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0;
    result = 31 * result + (status != null ? status.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (enabled != null ? enabled.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (timestamp != null ? timestamp.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}
}
```

And

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AccountsDetailData", schema = "dbo", catalog = "core")
public class AccountsDetailDataEntity {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@Basic
@Column(name = "additionalValue")
private String additionalValue;

@Basic
@Column(name = "status")
private String status;

@Basic
@Column(name = "enabled")
private Boolean enabled;

@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
private AccountsEntity accountsEntityObject;


public AccountsDetailDataEntity() {
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public String getAdditionalValue() {
    return additionalValue;
}

public void setAdditionalValue(String additionalValue) {
    this.additionalValue = additionalValue;
}


public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}


public Boolean getEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}

public void setEnabled(Boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    AccountsDetailDataEntity that = (AccountsDetailDataEntity) o;

    if (additionalValue != null ? !additionalValue.equals(that.additionalValue) : that.additionalValue != null)
        return false;
    if (enabled != null ? !enabled.equals(that.enabled) : that.enabled != null) return false;
    if (id != null ? !id.equals(that.id) : that.id != null) return false;
    if (status != null ? !status.equals(that.status) : that.status != null) return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0;
    result = 31 * result + (additionalValue != null ? additionalValue.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (status != null ? status.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (enabled != null ? enabled.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}
}
```

When I run this code:

```
Session session = getCoreObject().getDataBase().getCoreSession();
AccountsEntity fieldsEntity = (AccountsEntity) session.load(AccountsEntity.class,1);
```

I have exception:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.company.hrplus.core.rest.Account.enteties.AccountsDetailDataEntity column: id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

I can't understant where is the problem. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stacktrace is suggesting that the `id` column not be persisted but realistically you just need to change the join column name so it no longer conflicts with the primary key

```
@JoinColumn(name = "accounts_entity_id")
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess u have 2 columns called ID; ons is the PK column of entity AccountsDetailDataEntity coinciding with the declaration:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
```

the other one is the joincolumn; try to change name to the joincolumn or to the id column

I hope this can help

Angelo